# Square root function (math.h) - C

Tags: c

I think that my problem is very stupid... My function doesn't return a decimal value, but an int value... How can I solve this? Thanks!

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <math.h>

        int main()
        {
          //Dichiarazione variabili
          int nCasuale, i, MAX = 0, min = 100;
          float radice;

          //Generazione numeri casuali
          srand(time(NULL));

          for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) //Ciclo numeri casuali
            {
              nCasuale = 1 + rand() % 100; //Casuale tra 1 e 100
              printf("Numero casuale[%d]: %d\n", i, nCasuale); //Lo stampo

              radice = sqrt(nCasuale); //Radice del numero
              printf("Radice quadrata(%d)= %2.f\n\n", nCasuale, radice); //Stampo
```

And so on...

I don't understand why... Thanks for help =)

Comment: What do you mean "it returns an int value"?  What output do you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: because you're using an int and main is set to return an int.

Comment: ``sqrt()`` returns a double, so define ``radice`` as a double or use ``sqrtf()``.

Comment: You're also invoking [Undefined Behaviour](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior) by calling `time()` without a prototype in scope (eg: the compiler will assume the argument is of type `int` rather the `time_t*` and the result of conversion may wreak havoc ... *or may make `sqrt()` return a value of type `int`*).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are printing the square root with the format specifier `"%2.f"`, this tells `printf()`  to suppress any digits after the decimal point.

You probably meant `"%.2f"` to get two fractional digits.